# How to CountDistinct with two different datasets in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have two datasets and i want to count distinct. Customer are new purchasers calculated_x with regarding the 12 rolling month if they have none purchase. Customer_Y it's the same but with another value of the parameter. I can't join the two datasets to select distinct because after i want to realize it with many datasets.

```
D1 :
CommercialName customer_X
James.          2800
James.          999999
Paul.           420000

D2 : 
CommercialName  customer_Y
James.          5500
James.          6600
James.          999999
Paul.           420000
```

Tablix that i have :

```
CommercialName count_x   Count_y  
James            2.       3
Paul.            1.       1
```

Tablix that i want to get :

```
CommercialName count_Customer_XY
James            4.
Paul.            1.
```

Instead of

```
James 5
Paul 2
```

**Answer about sources:**

D1 :

```
SalesManagement_Code, SalesManagement_Name, SalesPerson_Code, SalesPerson_Name, Customer_Code, Customer_Name
```

The query contains 4 parameters: start date, end date, product types and product groups (group1)

D2 :

```
SalesManagement_Code, SalesManagement_Name, SalesPerson_Code, SalesPerson_Name, Customer_Code, Customer_Name
```

The query contains also 4 parameters: start date, end date, product types. But instead of having the same parameter of product group, I created an internal parameter with default values with this expression : iif(parameterGroupe1 = 01, 05, 01) so that the calculation is made on another product group.

In fact, I could make a distinct on the customers with a join between the two queries but these queries are each 82 rows long and I plan to do this for others product groups and the final query could be  huge.

Comment: What are the 2 dataset sources? e.g. tables, views, stored procedure, XML.

Comment: It's sql request. Sql text query

Comment: Can you post both sources? 
e.g. Selectt statements

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with formatting the SQL into one dataset and UNION them.

```
WITH 
group1 
AS
(
   SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
    ( 'James', 5500)
   , ( 'James', 6600)
   , ( 'James', 999999)
   , ( 'Paul', 420000)
   ) tbl ([Customer_Name], [Customer_Code]) 
)
, 
group2
AS
(
   SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
    ( 'James', 2800)
   , ( 'James', 999999)
   , ( 'Paul', 420000)
   ) tbl ([Customer_Name], [Customer_Code]) 
)
SELECT 
    [Customer_Code]
   , [Customer_Name]
FROM
   group1
UNION
SELECT 
    [Customer_Code]
   , [Customer_Name]
FROM
   group2
ORDER BY 2;
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, i know that i can do it with a distinct join but i want to do it with approximatively 20 different query because i have many product groups and each query is 82 rows long. I want to know if it is possible to do the distinct in the tablix, not in request conceptor

Comment: Can anyone give me more information please